# Should I declare this variable locally or globally?

Tags: java

I'm solving codechef's INTEST (https://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST), and here is my code so far:

```
 //to scan input
import java.util.Scanner;

class Intest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int lines, divisor, counter;
        int temporary;

        //get input for problem
        lines = keyboard.nextInt();
        divisor = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
            temporary = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (temporary % divisor == 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        //displays how many ints are divisible by the divisor
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Should I declare "temporary" locally instead?

Comment: yes, `int temporary = keyboard.nextInt();`  You may want to add some user prompts as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `temporary` outside the `for` loop, so it could be made local to the `for` without any change to behavior.

Comment: would that be most efficient? by making a new int every time the loop runs through?

Comment: It has nothing to do with efficiency, and everything to do with readability and reducing cognitive load. In this case the difference is miniscule, but in a large system reducing the scope of variables will make it easier for the next maintainer to reason about the code's intent and behavior.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Not really, it's a fairly sound principle being applied.

Comment: I apologize, I'm still unfamiliar with all stackoverflow has to offer.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to initialize the variable counter to 0, otherwise there will be an error: The local variable i may not have been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do away with `temporary` altogether as follows?

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    if (keyboard.nextInt() % divisor == 0) {
       counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends. In some cases, yes, in some cases, no. If you're starting out with coding, then do what is simplest and clearest to you. As you build experience you will be able to decide when and how to alter code to make it better (aka 'refactoring'). Good on you for questioning if a particular way to write code is good or not and not just focusing on whether it 'works'. You might find this book interesting https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html